# Itext PDF works slowly with Paragraph

Tags: java, json, performance, pdf, itext

I have a task to create a PDF file with maximum of 10000 records. Each record is a Java object in JSON representation. 10 objects are ~15000 bytes (`jsonString.length()`). The resulting file with 1000 records takes ~900 KB on disk. I then do:

```java
private static Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
document.open();

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Paragraph("Title", font));

String jsonString = "{....}"; // 10 objects; jsonString.length()==15000
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // add 1000 objects
    p.add(new Paragraph(jsonString, font));

document.add(p);
document.close();
```

But when I run this code I'm waiting 80s. Why it so slow? Is it possible to do it faster?

#### UPDATE

When I used single Paragraph with only 200 objects it worked even slower:

```java
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("{......}"); // ~300_000 bytes
document.add(p);
```

It takes 2 mins to save 200 objects as PDF instead of 1.5 min for 1000 objects as in first case.

Comment: Why do you add all those small paragraphs to that big paragraph instead of to the document directly?

Comment: It is weird, but when I tested with one Paragraph it works even slower. See update in my question

Comment: I've just submitted an edit on the code above, as the lack of curly braces and weird indentation didn't make it obvious as to what your original strategy was (only adding the Paragraph to the document at the end of the cycle), as opposed to what you are suggesting as a solution to your problem (adding the Paragraphs to the Document as you go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but with OpenPdf library. I created pdf file with 10000 records from 7 to 17 seconds and pdf size from 4 to 32 MB, depending on single record size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("OpenPDF-example.pdf"));
    //setting font family, color
    Font font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10);
    doc.open();
    for (int j=0; j<10000; j++) {
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("single record from 1 to 5kB", font);
        doc.add(para);
    }
    doc.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

Note, it is required to add data by small paragraphs. When I tried to add all data in one paragraphs it worked very slowly (more than 10 min).

Comment: Using small Paragraphs is significantly faster!